# Just want to pass image via image id

Tags: android

Got some code ,its working fine but I want to sent the images by its ImageView id not like fixed image as

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

I tried putting `R.id.myimageId` in place of `R.drawable.ic_launcher`  but its not working.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use existing image from an `ImageView`, you have to use

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Here,`img` is your `ImageView`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me...I just wasted my 2-3 hours on this.